# How to check the condition MRP price and Selling price in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

How to check the MRP prices and selling prices are equal or not equal. Suppose if MRP price and Selling price are equal have to display only selling price in text view otherwise both MRP price and selling price must display in text view.

Program:

```
 String sellingprice=prodcutitems.getString("selling_price");
  String productMrp=prodcutitems.getString("mrp_price");
   if(productMrp==sellingprice) {
     existingprice[k].setText(sellingprice);
                                }
           else
                               {
    existingprice[k].setText(sellingprice);
   price[k].setText(productMrp);
   existingprice[k].setPaintFlags(existingprice[k].getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                               }
                                                        }
```

I have been checking like this only else part can worked.
  Thanks in Advance

Comment: if( TextUtils.equals(productMrp,sellingprice) )

Comment: if(productMrp.equals(sellingprice))

Comment: if(sellingprice.equals(productMrp) { your code..} else {}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Three of checking condition worked well Thanks a lot dhina

Comment: one more doubt  i have two date start date and end date,if start and end date there is null selling price will display otherwise if there is date between start and end date offer price will display in textview.so have to use timestamp to checking this date to display offer price.How to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This....

Program:

```
String sellingprice=prodcutitems.getString("selling_price");
  String productMrp=prodcutitems.getString("mrp_price");
   if(productMrp.equalsIgnoreCase(sellingprice)) {
     existingprice[k].setText(sellingprice);
                                }
           else
                               {
    existingprice[k].setText(sellingprice);
   price[k].setText(productMrp);
   existingprice[k].setPaintFlags(existingprice[k].getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                               }
}
```